# Export the actual value of the variable inside the function

Tags: javascript

I need to export (for using variables in other scripts and other .js files)  the actual value of a variable inside a function, how i can do that?

Global variables with zero values are set, they change their values inside functions, I need to export these values only after the function is executed.

the variables that need to be exported are commented out inside the function.

```
let numberOfTracks = null;
let tracks = '';
let musicid = null;
let dude = '';
let currentTrack = null;
let pathForTrack = '';

    const generateTracksBox = function () {
        for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfTracks; i++) {  
            $(`<div class="container card chartsCard" data-musicid="${i}">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="/AppMusic/assets/chartLogo/${i}.svg" alt="Card image cap"></img>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">${tracks[i-1].split('-')[0]}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">${tracks[i-1].split('-')[1]}</p>
                </div>
            </div`).appendTo('.charts');
        }
        const dude = $('.chartsCard'); 
        for (let i = 0; i < dude.length; i++) {    
            dude[i].onclick = function () {
                currentTrack = $(dude[i]).data('musicid'); //need to export
                location.href = "music/player.html";
            }
        }
    }
    
    const getTracksArray = function () {
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', `/AppMusic/assets/tracks`);
            xhr.responseType = 'text';
            xhr.onload = function () {
                const pathsForTracks = new RegExp('(?<=href="\)(.+?)(?=")', 'g');
                const nameOf = new RegExp('(?<=mp3">)(.+?)(?=.mp3)', 'g');
                numberOfTracks = xhr.response.match(nameOf).length; // need to export
                tracks = xhr.response.match(nameOf)
                generateTracksBox()
                pathForTrack = xhr.response.match(pathsForTracks) // need to export
            }
            xhr.send();
    }
```

Comment: What does "export" mean here?

Comment: That value is only set after clicking on an item.  Since i don't see `currentTrack` defined anywhere, I'm guessing it's some kind of global variable?  If so, you're already "exporting" that value whenever you click on whatever `dude[i]` is.  You'd use the same `currentTrack` variable after.

Comment: I believe what you mean by *export* is returning a value (asynchronously) from that function. But you could of course export the function itself making the function and thus it's return value available to callers outside the current module. Anyway, to return a value asynchronously Promises are certainly the most modern and straightforward way to do so. Having said that, consider using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) instead of your xhr requests.

Comment: Global variables with zero values are set, they change their values inside functions, I need to export these values only after the function is executed

Comment: export to where? you haven't provided any code where you want to use that variable. does `return currentTrack;` not work?

Comment: @Rick for using variables in other scripts and other .js files
https://i.gyazo.com/1fba67a4980207bbf2fddba638cd7d98.png

Comment: From a programming perspective, it might be best to never use global variables inside functions. Instead pass in the values and pass updated values back out and only use the globals outside of your functions.

Comment: The first thing that came into my mind, is the use of an Observable pattern, with you observers subscribing to the change of this value, as I beleive it can be implemented with Rxjs

Comment: @TheDnino, ow looks like a solution, ty

Comment: @Mirikkingg, ure welcome, If it did help you, don't forget to upvote, thank you!